# How can I enforce a minimum Bluetooth MTU for an Android app?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I'm working with a piece of hardware that sends and receives packets of data over particular BLE characteristics. Currently, each packet has to be an individual read or write.

When talking to the device from iOS, with the MTU negotiated up to 157 bytes, it's easy to observe this limitation. It's also easy to confirm that this MTU negotiation will work on the entire range of Apple devices the app needs to support. Without MTU negotiation, we would be limited to the default 23 byte ATT MTU, meaning we could only send and receive 20 byte packets (due to GATT overhead). The data format used for certain features will not fit in a 20 byte packet.

In the near future we'll be porting the app to Android and eventually releasing it for public consumption. I know that the Android API provides the `requestMtu()` method for attempting MTU negotiation, but if a user's Android device does not support an ATT MTU higher than the default 23 bytes, we'd like to be able to tell the user as soon as possible that the app will be unable to perform certain functions. Ideally, we'd like to stop the user from installing the app on such a device.

Is there a way to detect (directly or indirectly) the BLE MTU capabilities of an Android device without first requiring the user to connect to a BLE peripheral?

(Note: I've encountered a few anecdotes claiming that assorted Android devices only support the 23 byte default, but these mostly seem to come from developers who don't know about MTU negotiation. It's possible that all extant Android devices support higher MTUs. I don't know whether this is true.)

Answer (score 0):

Can you give an example of an Android device that does not support something higher than the default MTU?

What I have heard all Android devices should support a higher MTU than the default. The only problem is for 4.3 and 4.4 which does not have the requestMtu API, but then you can simply initiate the MTU change from the peripheral instead.

Comment: I don't know that any such devices exist. I have no trustworthy data on what's out there. I'll edit the question to reflect this.